# how could i know the version of an another application using c#

Tags: c#, process, version

i need to write a program in c# to collect information about processes running on my computer. I successfuly get the processes's names and ID using this code:

...
Process[] processlist;
...
foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine(theprocess.ProcessName + ...)
                }
...

But i couldn't get the version of the processes (like Firefox or Visual Studio).
does anybody know how to get the version of a running process?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

theProcess.MainModule.FileVersionInfo. But there are one or two exceptions you need to catch.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the filename of the executable from Process.StartInfo.FileName. Get a new instance of [FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo_members.aspx) using the filename like this:

```
FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Process.StartInfo.FileName);
```

Then access myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion to get the file version.

EDIT: Daniel's way seems more efficient; I didn't know you could just access the loaded module's FileVersionInfo directly..

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the executable's FileVersion and/or ProductVersion may not necessarily be the same as the application's version. For example, Firefox 3.5.3 reports a FileVersion of 1.9.1.3523, but a ProductVersion of 3.5.3. VMware Player 2.5.1, on the other hand, reports a FileVersion of 6.5.1.5078 and a ProductVersion of 6.5.1 build-126130.
Depending on what you are using the information for, this may or may not be an issue.